# Return error message when start-up fails with systemd unit file for playframework

Tags: playframework, systemd

I have this systemd unit file to start a play app:

```
# Systemd unit file for playapp
[Unit]
Description=Run Server for playapp
Wants=syslog.target network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
PIDFile=/opt/playapp/play.pid

ExecStart=/opt/playapp/bin/playapp
ExecStop=/bin/kill $MAINPID
Restart=always
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

- With `Type=simple` there is no feedback if the start-up with `systemctl start playapp.service` fails.
- With `Type=forking` there is an error if start-up fails, but the `systemctl start playapp.service` stays in the foreground of the shell, if there is no error in start-up.

What is the best way to start a play application with systemd? (With an error message if the start-up isn't successful)

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way : The service just starts java with a number of arguments. If things fail (usually during DI initialisation), the service terminates. The service (read : The startup of java) is however successful : It just terminates during startup.

Systemd notices that, and restarts it if required. The error however, is directed to the Play logfiles, for which systemd has no notice off. We just accepted that as a fact, and tail if needed (actually, we redirect all logging to a central systlog server, but that's just an implementation detail).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I can't upvote the answer yet (too less reputation).

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that systemd doesn't know how long to wait for the process to error out.

For "type=simple" systemd forks a process, and then runs that in the background. Since systemd has no way to know when initialization is done, and initialization can take an arbitrarily long time, systemd simply starts the service and returns immediately.

One normal solution is to use "type=forking", and then make your program do the forking, and only fork when initialization has successfully completed and we know the daemon can run. Systemd waits for the forking process to exit, and interprets this as meaning the initialization is done and can then give feedback to you on the command line. Since playapp is presumably not designed to fork like this, you can't immediately use "type=forking".

Another solutions is to use "type=notify", where the daemon doesn't fork, but sends a message to systemd when it is sucessfully initialized. Systemd can then wait for this. Since I assume that playapp is not designed for this either, this can't be immediately used either.

But what you can do is to write your own forking shell script, which forks out a playapp process. Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     
/bin/playapp &
PID=$!
sleep 2
if [ -n "$PID" -a -e /proc/$PID ]; then
    echo "process $PID exists"
    exit 0
else
    echo "process $PID doesn't exist"
    exit 1
fi
```

(remember to `chmod +x` it). Here you should replace the "sleep 2" to however long you guess playapp takes to initialize. Perhaps even make a loop which exits sooner if the playapp dies sooner.

If you then made a service file with `ExecStart=/local/bin/thescript.sh` and `Type=forking`, then it seems to work. I did not have to specify any PID file for it to work in my test; I assume that since the forked process is a child of the script, systemd figures the PID out automatically.

The test systemd service I tested with looked like this (I just had a `/bin/sleep 3 &` in `/local/bin/thescript.sh` instead of `playapp`):

```
# Systemd unit file for playapp
[Unit]
Description=Run Server for playapp
Wants=syslog.target network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/local/bin/thescript.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```